# PHP DomDocument - getAllChildrenByTagName

Tags: php, domdocument, children

Is there a function like "getAllChildrenByTagName" in PHP?

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXML('<p><a id="1">test 1</a><span><a id="2">test 2</a></span></p>');
foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName('a') AS $node)
    echo($node->textContent);
```

Here i only want the a-Tag with "id = 1". Is it possible?

Comment: Note that in a valid HTML document there **should be** only one element with the ID `"a"`.

Comment: @nickb What about links, i.e: `<a href="http://www.google.com>Google</a>` or do you mean that all element id's should be unique?

Comment: I meant only one element with ID `"1"`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can to use XPath to directly grab the element you're looking for:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXML('<p><a id="1">test 1</a><span><a id="2">test 2</a></span></p>');

$xpath = new DOMXpath( $dom);
$a = $xpath->query( '//a[@id="1"]')->item( 0);
echo $a->textContent;
```

This [will print](http://viper-7.com/sKYn3Y):

```
test 1
```

Comment: +1 for beating me to the punch.  Good catch.  Specifying the first index `->item(0);` will ensure that only one element is returned instead of a `DOMNodeList`.

Answer (score 1):

It would be best to use XPath here.  Take a look at the following PHP code.

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXML('<p><a id="1">test 1</a><span><a id="2">test 2</a></span></p>');
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);
$elements = $xpath->query("//a[@id='1']");
```

Answer (score 0):

No, not with getElementsbyTagName.

Better use a XPath query, they where 'invented' to do these things.